# Click on input field applies a background colour on parent and deselect initial selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I have one input field and 2 radio buttons, in same line.
When i click on a radio button, a background colour is applied on it's parent.

I needed to fix 2 issues, if possible:

1. when i click on input field, apply active class like it is done when I select a radio button
2. if i click on radio button and then on input field (or currency dropdown), remove the checked option from initial radio button

Both 2 issues were solved by Praveen Kumar (thanks) but unfortunately, now i run into another issue. I am using [sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) which converts the input for currency and now, if i click on the currency, it will not work at all. If i duplicate currency and place it outside of price input block, will work just fine so there must be a conflict which i can't find (i've wasted 1 day before i updated this post).

I have updated the jsfiddle with sumoselect and the fix from Praveen Kumar so you can see the issue

```js
$('.price input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
  $('input:not(:checked)').parent('label').removeClass("active");
  $('input:checked').parent('label').addClass("active");
});
$("#price, .SlectBox").focus(function () {
  $("label").removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest('label').addClass("active");
  $("input:checked").prop("checked", false);
}).blur(function () {
  if ($("#price").val().length == 0)
    $(this).closest('label').removeClass("active");
});



/*!
 * jquery.sumoselect - v2.1.0
 * http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect
 */ 

! function(e) {
    "namespace sumo";
    e.fn.SumoSelect = function(t) {
        var l = e.extend({
                placeholder: "Select Here",
                csvDispCount: 3,
                captionFormat: "{0} Selected",
                floatWidth: 400,
                forceCustomRendering: !1,
                nativeOnDevice: ["Android", "BlackBerry", "iPhone", "iPad", "iPod", "Opera Mini", "IEMobile", "Silk"],
                outputAsCSV: !1,
                csvSepChar: ",",
                okCancelInMulti: !1,
                triggerChangeCombined: !0,
                selectAll: !1,
                selectAlltext: "Select All"
            }, t),
            s = this.each(function() {
                var t = this;
                !this.sumo && e(this).is("select") && (this.sumo = {
                    E: e(t),
                    is_multi: e(t).attr("multiple"),
                    select: "",
                    caption: "",
                    placeholder: "",
                    optDiv: "",
                    CaptionCont: "",
                    is_floating: !1,
                    is_opened: !1,
                    mob: !1,
                    Pstate: [],
                    createElems: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        return t.E.wrap('<div class="SumoSelect" tabindex="0">'), t.select = t.E.parent(), t.caption = e("<span></span>"), t.CaptionCont = e('<p class="CaptionCont"><i></i></p>').addClass("SlectBox").attr("style", t.E.attr("style")).prepend(t.caption), t.select.append(t.CaptionCont), t.E.attr("disabled") && t.select.addClass("disabled").removeAttr("tabindex"), l.outputAsCSV && t.is_multi && t.E.attr("name") && (t.select.append(e('<input class="HEMANT123" type="hidden" />').attr("name", t.E.attr("name")).val(t.getSelStr())), t.E.removeAttr("name")), t.isMobile() && !l.forceCustomRendering ? void t.setNativeMobile() : (t.E.hide(), t.optDiv = e('<div class="optWrapper">'), t.floatingList(), ul = e('<ul class="options">'), t.optDiv.append(ul), l.selectAll && t.selAll(), e(t.E.children("option")).each(function(l, i) {
                            i = e(i), t.createLi(i)
                        }), t.is_multi && t.multiSelelect(), t.select.append(t.optDiv), t.basicEvents(), void t.selAllState())
                    },
                    createLi: function(t, l) {
                        var i = this;
                        return t.attr("value") || t.attr("value", t.val()), li = e('<li data-val="' + t.val() + '"><label>' + t.text() + "</label></li>"), i.is_multi && li.prepend("<span><i></i></span>"), t[0].disabled && (li = li.addClass("disabled")), i.onOptClick(li), t[0].selected && li.addClass("selected"), t.attr("class") && li.addClass(t.attr("class")), ul = i.optDiv.children("ul.options"), "undefined" == typeof l ? ul.append(li) : ul.children("li").eq(l).before(li), li
                    },
                    getSelStr: function() {
                        return sopt = [], this.E.children("option:selected").each(function() {
                            sopt.push(e(this).val())
                        }), sopt.join(l.csvSepChar)
                    },
                    multiSelelect: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        t.optDiv.addClass("multiple"), t.okbtn = e('<p class="btnOk">OK</p>').click(function() {
                            l.triggerChangeCombined && (changed = !1, t.E.children("option:selected").length != t.Pstate.length ? changed = !0 : t.E.children("option:selected").each(function() {
                                t.Pstate.indexOf(e(this).val()) < 0 && (changed = !0)
                            }), changed && (t.E.trigger("change").trigger("click"), t.setText())), t.hideOpts()
                        }), t.cancelBtn = e('<p class="btnCancel">Cancel</p>').click(function() {
                            t._cnbtn(), t.hideOpts()
                        }), t.optDiv.append(e('<div class="MultiControls">').append(t.okbtn).append(t.cancelBtn))
                    },
                    _cnbtn: function() {
                        var e = this;
                        for (e.E.children("option:selected").each(function() {
                                this.selected = !1
                            }), e.optDiv.find("li.selected").removeClass("selected"), i = 0; i < e.Pstate.length; i++) e.E.children('option[value="' + e.Pstate[i] + '"]')[0].selected = !0, e.optDiv.find('li[data-val="' + e.Pstate[i] + '"]').addClass("selected");
                        e.selAllState()
                    },
                    selAll: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        t.is_multi && (t.chkAll = e("<i>"), t.selAll = e('<p class="select-all"><label>' + l.selectAlltext + "</label></p>").prepend(e("<span></span>").append(t.chkAll)), t.chkAll.on("click", function() {
                            t.selAll.toggleClass("selected"), t.optDiv.find("ul.options li").each(function(l, i) {
                                i = e(i), t.selAll.hasClass("selected") ? i.hasClass("selected") || i.trigger("click") : i.hasClass("selected") && i.trigger("click")
                            })
                        }), t.optDiv.prepend(t.selAll))
                    },
                    selAllState: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        if (l.selectAll) {
                            var i = 0,
                                s = 0;
                            t.optDiv.find("ul.options li").each(function(t, l) {
                                e(l).hasClass("selected") && i++, e(l).hasClass("disabled") || s++
                            }), i == s ? t.selAll.removeClass("partial").addClass("selected") : 0 == i ? t.selAll.removeClass("selected partial") : t.selAll.addClass("partial")
                        }
                    },
                    showOpts: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        t.E.attr("disabled") || (t.is_opened = !0, t.optDiv.addClass("open"), e(document).on("click.sumo", function(e) {
                            if (!t.select.is(e.target) && 0 === t.select.has(e.target).length) {
                                if (!t.is_opened) return;
                                t.hideOpts(), t.is_multi && l.okCancelInMulti && t._cnbtn()
                            }
                        }), t.is_floating && (H = t.optDiv.children("ul").outerHeight() + 2, t.is_multi && (H += parseInt(t.optDiv.css("padding-bottom"))), t.optDiv.css("height", H)), t.is_multi && (t.is_floating || l.okCancelInMulti) && (t.Pstate = [], t.E.children("option:selected").each(function() {
                            t.Pstate.push(e(this).val())
                        })))
                    },
                    hideOpts: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        t.is_opened = !1, t.optDiv.removeClass("open").find("ul li.sel").removeClass("sel"), e(document).off("click.sumo")
                    },
                    setOnOpen: function() {
                        var e = this,
                            t = e.optDiv.find("ul li").eq(e.E[0].selectedIndex);
                        t.addClass("sel"), e.showOpts()
                    },
                    nav: function(e) {
                        var t, l = this,
                            i = l.optDiv.find("ul li.sel");
                        if (l.is_opened && i.length) {
                            if (t = e ? i.prevAll("li:not(.disabled)") : i.nextAll("li:not(.disabled)"), !t.length) return;
                            i.removeClass("sel"), i = t.first().addClass("sel");
                            var s = l.optDiv.find("ul"),
                                n = s.scrollTop(),
                                o = i.position().top + n;
                            o >= n + s.height() - i.outerHeight() && s.scrollTop(o - s.height() + i.outerHeight()), n > o && s.scrollTop(o)
                        } else l.setOnOpen()
                    },
                    basicEvents: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        t.CaptionCont.click(function(e) {
                            t.E.trigger("click"), t.is_opened ? t.hideOpts() : t.showOpts(), e.stopPropagation()
                        }), t.select.on("keydown", function(e) {
                            switch (e.which) {
                                case 38:
                                    t.nav(!0);
                                    break;
                                case 40:
                                    t.nav(!1);
                                    break;
                                case 32:
                                case 13:
                                    t.is_opened ? t.optDiv.find("ul li.sel").trigger("click") : t.setOnOpen();
                                    break;
                                case 9:
                                case 27:
                                    return t.is_multi && l.okCancelInMulti && t._cnbtn(), void t.hideOpts();
                                default:
                                    return
                            }
                            e.preventDefault()
                        }), e(window).on("resize.sumo", function() {
                            t.floatingList()
                        })
                    },
                    onOptClick: function(t) {
                        var i = this;
                        t.click(function() {
                            var t = e(this);
                            t.hasClass("disabled") || (txt = "", i.is_multi ? (t.toggleClass("selected"), i.E.children('option[value="' + t.data("val") + '"]')[0].selected = t.hasClass("selected"), i.selAllState()) : (t.parent().find("li.selected").removeClass("selected"), t.toggleClass("selected"), i.E.val(t.attr("data-val"))), i.is_multi && l.triggerChangeCombined && (i.is_floating || l.okCancelInMulti) || (i.setText(), i.E.trigger("change").trigger("click")), i.is_multi || i.hideOpts())
                        })
                    },
                    setText: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        if (t.placeholder = "", t.is_multi) {
                            for (sels = t.E.children(":selected").not(":disabled"), i = 0; i < sels.length; i++) {
                                if (i >= l.csvDispCount && l.csvDispCount) {
                                    t.placeholder = l.captionFormat.replace("{0}", sels.length);
                                    break
                                }
                                t.placeholder += e(sels[i]).text() + ", "
                            }
                            t.placeholder = t.placeholder.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, "$1")
                        } else t.placeholder = t.E.children(":selected").not(":disabled").text();
                        return is_placeholder = !1, t.placeholder || (is_placeholder = !0, t.placeholder = t.E.attr("placeholder"), t.placeholder || (t.placeholder = t.E.children("option:disabled:selected").text())), t.placeholder = t.placeholder ? t.placeholder : l.placeholder, t.caption.text(t.placeholder), csvField = t.select.find("input.HEMANT123"), csvField.length && csvField.val(t.getSelStr()), is_placeholder ? t.caption.addClass("placeholder") : t.caption.removeClass("placeholder"), t.placeholder
                    },
                    isMobile: function() {
                        for (var e = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, t = 0; t < l.nativeOnDevice.length; t++)
                            if (e.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(l.nativeOnDevice[t].toLowerCase()) > 0) return l.nativeOnDevice[t];
                        return !1
                    },
                    setNativeMobile: function() {
                        var e = this;
                        e.E.addClass("SelectClass"), e.mob = !0, e.E.change(function() {
                            e.setText()
                        })
                    },
                    floatingList: function() {
                        var t = this;
                        t.is_floating = e(window).width() <= l.floatWidth, t.optDiv.toggleClass("isFloating", t.is_floating), t.is_floating || t.optDiv.css("height", ""), t.optDiv.toggleClass("okCancelInMulti", l.okCancelInMulti && !t.is_floating)
                    },
                    vRange: function(e) {
                        var t = this;
                        if (opts = t.E.children("option"), opts.length <= e || 0 > e) throw "index out of bounds";
                        return t
                    },
                    toggSel: function(e, t) {
                        var l = this.vRange(t);
                        l.E.children("option")[t].disabled || (l.E.children("option")[t].selected = e, l.mob || l.optDiv.find("ul.options li").eq(t).toggleClass("selected", e), l.setText())
                    },
                    toggDis: function(e, t) {
                        var l = this.vRange(t);
                        l.E.children("option")[t].disabled = e, e && (l.E.children("option")[t].selected = !1), l.mob || l.optDiv.find("ul.options li").eq(t).toggleClass("disabled", e).removeClass("selected"), l.setText()
                    },
                    toggSumo: function(e) {
                        var t = this;
                        return t.enabled = e, t.select.toggleClass("disabled", e), e ? (t.E.attr("disabled", "disabled"), t.select.removeAttr("tabindex")) : (t.E.removeAttr("disabled"), t.select.attr("tabindex", "0")), t
                    },
                    toggSelAll: function(t) {
                        var i = this;
                        i.E.find("option").each(function(l, s) {
                            i.E.find("option")[e(this).index()].disabled || (i.E.find("option")[e(this).index()].selected = t, i.mob || i.optDiv.find("ul.options li").eq(e(this).index()).toggleClass("selected", t), i.setText())
                        }), !i.mob && l.selectAll && i.selAll.removeClass("partial").toggleClass("selected", t)
                    },
                    reload: function() {
                        var t = this.unload();
                        return e(t).SumoSelect(l)
                    },
                    unload: function() {
                        var e = this;
                        return e.select.before(e.E), e.E.show(), l.outputAsCSV && e.is_multi && e.select.find("input.HEMANT123").length && e.E.attr("name", e.select.find("input.HEMANT123").attr("name")), e.select.remove(), delete t.sumo, t
                    },
                    add: function(l, i, s) {
                        if ("undefined" == typeof l) throw "No value to add";
                        var n = this;
                        if (opts = n.E.children("option"), "number" == typeof i && (s = i, i = l), "undefined" == typeof i && (i = l), opt = e("<option></option>").val(l).html(i), opts.length < s) throw "index out of bounds";
                        return "undefined" == typeof s || opts.length == s ? (n.E.append(opt), n.mob || n.createLi(opt)) : (opts.eq(s).before(opt), n.mob || n.createLi(opt, s)), t
                    },
                    remove: function(e) {
                        var t = this.vRange(e);
                        t.E.children("option").eq(e).remove(), t.mob || t.optDiv.find("ul.options li").eq(e).remove(), t.setText()
                    },
                    selectItem: function(e) {
                        this.toggSel(!0, e)
                    },
                    unSelectItem: function(e) {
                        this.toggSel(!1, e)
                    },
                    selectAll: function() {
                        this.toggSelAll(!0)
                    },
                    unSelectAll: function() {
                        this.toggSelAll(!1)
                    },
                    disableItem: function(e) {
                        this.toggDis(!0, e)
                    },
                    enableItem: function(e) {
                        this.toggDis(!1, e)
                    },
                    enabled: !0,
                    enable: function() {
                        return this.toggSumo(!1)
                    },
                    disable: function() {
                        return this.toggSumo(!0)
                    },
                    init: function() {
                        var e = this;
                        return e.createElems(), e.setText(), e
                    }
                }, t.sumo.init())
            });
        return 1 == s.length ? s[0] : s
    }
}(jQuery);



$(function(){
  $('select').SumoSelect({ 
    nativeOnDevice: ['Android', 'BlackBerry', 'iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod', 'Opera Mini', 'IEMobile', 'Silk'],
  });
  $('.selector > #select_1').SumoSelect();
});
```

```css
.price label {
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.active {
  background-color: #555 !important;
}


.SlectBox { box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;width: 100%; padding: 6px 5px 4px;}
.SumoSelect { position: relative;outline:none;color:#666;}
.header .SumoSelect {width: 100%;}
.add-item .price .SumoSelect {float: right;}
.add-item .price .SumoSelect label {}





/*this is applied on that hidden select. DO NOT USE display:none; or visiblity:hidden; and Do not override any of these properties. */
.SelectClass { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none; z-index: 1; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity: 0; -khtml-opacity: 0; opacity: 0; }

.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li label, .SumoSelect > .CaptionCont { user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; }


.SumoSelect:focus > .CaptionCont,.SumoSelect:hover > .CaptionCont {border-color: #7799D0;}
.SumoSelect > .CaptionCont { position: relative; border: 1px solid #A4A4A4; min-height: 14px; background-color: #fff;}
.search-options .SumoSelect > .CaptionCont {border: 0px;} 
.SumoSelect > .CaptionCont > span { display: block; padding-right: 30px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;cursor:default;}
/*placeholder style*/
.SumoSelect > .CaptionCont > span.placeholder { color: #ccc; font-style: italic; }

.SumoSelect > .CaptionCont > label { position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 30px;}
.SumoSelect > .CaptionCont > i { opacity:0.5; background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3wMdBhAJ/fwnjwAAAGFJREFUKM9jYBh+gBFKuzEwMKQwMDB8xaOWlYGB4T4DA0MrsuapDAwM//HgNwwMDDbYTJuGQ8MHBgYGJ1xOYGNgYJiBpuEpAwODHSF/siDZ+ISBgcGClEDqZ2Bg8B6CkQsAPRga0cpRtDEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');background-position: center center; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 10px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto;background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper { width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out, top 200ms ease-out, visibility 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out, top 200ms ease-out, visibility 200ms ease-out; -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out, top 200ms ease-out, visibility 200ms ease-out; -ms-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out, top 200ms ease-out, visibility 200ms ease-out; -o-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out, top 200ms ease-out, visibility 200ms ease-out; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; z-index: -100; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd; overflow: hidden;}
.search-options .SumoSelect > .optWrapper {border:0px;}
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper.open { top: 100%; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; z-index: 1000;margin-top: 2px; }

.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options { list-style: none; display: block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: auto; /*Set the height of pop up here (only for desktop mode)*/max-height: 250px;/*height*/ }
.search-options .SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options {height: 183px;} 
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper.isFloating > .options {max-height: 100%;}
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li { margin: 0;padding: 6px 6px; border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F3F3; position: relative; }

.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li:hover { background-color: #E4E4E4; }
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li.sel{background-color: #a1c0e4;}

.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li label { text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; display: block;cursor: pointer;padding: 0;margin: 0;}
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li span { display: none; }

/*Floating styles*/
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper.isFloating { position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: 90%; bottom: 0px; margin: auto; max-height: 90%; }


/*styling for optgroups*/
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options > li.optGroup { padding-left: 5px; text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price section-content">
  <label>
    <input id="price" type="text" value="" name="price">
    <select id="currency" name="currency">
      <option value="EUR">€</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="USD">$</option>
    </select>
    <span>Price</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input id="exchange" type="radio" value="2" name="price-option">
    <span>Exchange</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input id="donate" type="radio" value="1" name="price-option">
    <span>Donate</span>
  </label>
</div>
    <select id="currency" name="currency">
      <option value="EUR">€</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="USD">$</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Nope, is not working. Click on a radio button and active class is added (#555) and now click on the input field and you will see that active class is not added.

Comment: I got it and fixed it. Kindly check my answer and tell if it is okay?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly check now?

Comment: a improvement but...  i click on radio first. Than i click on price input field and the background flashes for a moment so the colour does not stay. If i click to insert a number the radio is deselected (ok) but if i select currency the radio or i click on the text Price , is not deselected. Just to explain better, any click on what's inside first label (with Price ) must deactivate selected radio and  apply the active class so that background changes.

Comment: **Refresh and see the updated answer please...**

Comment: Click on the Run Code Snippet and check.

Comment: Better. Colour stays now but can you deselect radio if i click on currency dropdown and apply the active background colour on it's parent like is happening when i click on input? Thanks

Comment: Hello Praveen Kumar. Can you please take a look at the updated code snippet? I must use sumoselect to style the input select (which can't be done via css) and when currency is converted by sumoselect it will not work when it is inside price block. If i place it outside price block, works just fine so it must be a conflict with your code and i didn't manage to find a fix. Maybe you can spot the issue. Thanks, again...

Comment: It doesn't even work something is preventing it from bubbling.

Comment: It works if you navigate using Keyboard. Type something, press tab, and press down. `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99622/discussion-between-adyyda-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle by adding another currency outside of price to see it working ok and have replaced in the jquery .currency with .SlectBox which is the name of the fake select. No luck. I see that when i use the one from outside price block, a "open" class is attached to expand it and when i use the one from price, that does not happen?

Comment: i have added       $('.price .SlectBox').click(function () {
            $('.optWrapper').toggleClass('open');
      }); to force it to work and on click currency opens and closes but works only for that outside of price.

Comment: Hello. You mentioned "For deselecting the inputs, you can use:

$("input:checked").prop("checked", false); ". Can you tell me what i can use to deselect the radio input if i click on currency select (dropdown)?

Comment: That is fixed like this     $('.SlectBox').click(function() { 
      $(this).closest('.option').toggleClass('active');
      $('input:checked').prop('checked', false); 
    });   and now, previous radio is deselected but active class is still attached to that radio and if i use $('input:checked').removeClass('active'); is not working...

Comment: Add `$('input:checked').prop('checked', false).closest("label").removeClass("active");` too.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Now it functions ok, including currency via sumoselect.

Comment: With your last code ( $('input:checked').prop('checked', false).closest("label").removeClass("active"); ) all is fine on PC but on a tablet with latest android, label does not deselect when i click on currency input. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Android tablet or phones as well? I can check in iPad. I don't have an android tablet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deselecting the inputs, you can use:

```
$("input:checked").prop("checked", false);
```

For the text `<input />`, you can use the following code:

```
$("#price").focus(function () {
  $(this).closest('label').addClass("active");
  $("input:checked").prop("checked", false);
}).blur(function () {
  $(this).closest('label').removeClass("active");
});
```

Give it in the `focus` of `input`.

```js
$('.price input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
  $('input:not(:checked)').parent('label').removeClass("active");
  $('input:checked').parent('label').addClass("active");
});
$("#price, #currency").focus(function () {
  $("label").removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest('label').addClass("active");
  $("input:checked").prop("checked", false);
}).blur(function () {
  if ($("#price").val().length == 0)
    $(this).closest('label').removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.price label {
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.active {
  background-color: #555 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price section-content">
  <label>
    <input id="price" type="text" value="" name="price">
    <select id="currency" name="currency">
      <option value="EUR">€</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="USD">$</option>
    </select>
    <span>Price</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input id="exchange" type="radio" value="2" name="price-option">
    <span>Exchange</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input id="donate" type="radio" value="1" name="price-option">
    <span>Donate</span>
  </label>
</div>
```